# How to return the result for arithmetic operations with lists using functions in Python

Tags: python, types, statistics

I'm trying to compute the mean, median and mode of a list of integers.  However, the error I'm getting (from what I've understood) states that I cannot return a floating point answer.  I don't understand why this is the case for lists.  All I'm doing is a basic arithmetic operation for both mean and median (using the statistics framework for mode).  The output should be just 1 single answer.

This is the code I have:

```py
from statistics import mode

listOfNumbers = [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 10, 10]
listOfNumbers.sort()
length = len(listOfNumbers)

def median(numbers):
  if((len(list)) % 2 == 0):
    median = (listOfNumbers[(length)/2] + listOfNumbers[(length)/2-1]) / 2
  else:
    median = listOfNumbers[(length-1)/2]
  return

def meanMedianMode(numbers):
    # TODO your code here!
    meanOfNumbers = (sum(numbers))/(len(numbers))
    medianOfNumbers = median(numbers)
    modeOfNumbers = mode(numbers)
    print("The mean of the numbers is: " + str(meanOfNumbers))
    print("The median of the numbers is: " + str(medianOfNumbers))
    print("The mode of the numbers is: " + str(modeOfNumbers))

meanMedianMode(listOfNumbers)
```

And this is my output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-03d94981e27d> in <module>()
     21     print("The mode of the numbers is: " + str(modeOfNumbers))
     22 
---> 23 meanMedianMode(listOfNumbers)
     24 

<ipython-input-27-03d94981e27d> in meanMedianMode(numbers)
     15     # TODO your code here!
     16     meanOfNumbers = (sum(numbers))/(len(numbers))
---> 17     medianOfNumbers = median(numbers)
     18     modeOfNumbers = mode(numbers)
     19     print("The mean of the numbers is: " + str(meanOfNumbers))

<ipython-input-27-03d94981e27d> in median(numbers)
      9     median = (listOfNumbers[(length)/2] + listOfNumbers[(length)/2-1]) / 2
     10   else:
---> 11     median = listOfNumbers[(length-1)/2]
     12   return
     13 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
median = listOfNumbers[(length-1)/2]
```

In python 3, `(length-1)/2` is a `float`, not an `int`, hence the error `list indices must be integers or slices, not float`

Easiest fix is to cast the result back into an `int`:

```
...
median = listOfNumbers[int((length - 1) / 2)]
...
```

In fact I would refactor your entire `median()` function like this, as you're mixing local and global variables, and not returning anything:

```
def median(numbers):
    length = len(numbers)
    if length % 2 == 0:
        return (listOfNumbers[int(length / 2)] + listOfNumbers[int(length / 2) - 1]) / 2
    else:
        return listOfNumbers[int((length - 1) / 2)]
```

Comment: He needs to fix the "return" lines as well

Comment: Thanks, @Danielle.  I've accepted and upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Answer (score 0):

Okay the fix:

```
    median_value = numbers[int((length - 1 )/2)]
    return median_value
```

A few of things here...

1. numbers[x] means the the xth elements in numbers so a value like 5.5 doesn't point to anything.
2. 6.0 is still a decimal number (or float), we want an integer so use int() so that this is now 6.
3. Ideally you want the median function to return these values after the list has been passed through (hence return median_value)

You would also have to do the same thing for the  other part of the if statement (not executed in this run).

```
   median_value = (numbers[int((length - 1)/2))] + numbers[int((length + 1)/2)]) / 2
   return median_value
```